# Browser must load and run in the background

Tags: blackberry, browser, java-me

The code below opens up the app and the browser loads and displays the specified url. Now what I want is for the the browser to load and run in the background after the app is opened.

```
public class start extends MainScreen {

    public start() {
        super();  // Call to super
        String url = ("http://www.google.com/");
        //A BrowserSession is created
        BrowserSession BS = Browser.getDefaultSession(); 
        BS.displayPage(url);
    }

    public boolean onClose() {
        System.exit(0);
        return true; // Close the system
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `UiApplication.getUiApplication().requestForeground()` after you called opening the url in browser.

I wouldn't suggest to call `System.exit()` inside the UI. Actually UI application will be closed as soon as last screen is closed.